# How to divide different divs on the same line along the width of a device in different resolutions?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of projects consists of multiples lines.Each line consists of 3 divs:

The first contain a logo.

The second contains the title, state and the date of the project.

The third contains some more infos.

I want to put the 3 divs on the same line and take in consideration the width of different resolutions of device into the display of the page.
index.html:

As a result I got the logo in a line and the two other divs in another line.How can I fix that?

```css
#list_project {
  position: relative;
  top: 120px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.project_logo {
  display: block;
  height: 60px;
}

.project_title {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Arial";
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

.project_status {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Arial Round MT Bold";
  color: #8e8e8e;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

.project_date {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Arial";
  color: #8e8e8e;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

.project_info_1 {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #e6e1e1;
  height: 63px;
}

.project_cost {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Arial";
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

.project_cost_1 {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Arial";
  color: #8e8e8e;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.2;
}
```

```html
<div id="list_project">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
        <img class="project_logo" src="./logos/logo.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="col col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="project_title"> Project 1 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="project_status">Active</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="project_date">03/2017-05/2018</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
        <table class="project_info_1">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="project_cost" name="project_cost">Cost:</td>
              <td class="project_cost_1" name="project_cost_1">140.000k$.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="project_cost" name="project_delay">Delay:</td>
              <td class="project_cost_1" name="project_delay_1">350 days.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="project_cost" name="project_load">Load:</td>
              <td class="project_cost_1" name="project_load_1">125 days.</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok First of all it won't work because you have `clas="..."` and not `class=".."`. So that alone won't make it work

Lastly, as a guide `"col col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4"` is not needed.
You can use only `"col col-sm-4 col-md-4"` because any resolution bigger will use the last 'highest span' found, if you know what I mean which in your case is `col-md-4` if you make the change, therefore `col-md-4` will be 4 for lg, xl, xxl as well.

You only add the `col-lg` and so on if there are to be of different span size

Comment: How to make the width of each div propotional to each column because I got a lot of space between three divs?

Comment: col-md-4 should do it...it will use the space of the screen. It looks that way because your not using bootstrap table. add `class='table'` inside you table div and it will expand properly

Example: <table class='table'>

Comment: you can also put 

`<table class='table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered table-hover'>`

Comment: I want to make the width of class="project_info_1" proportionally equal to the width of col in different device.

Comment: By adding what I had mentioned above will take care of that for you. The bootstrap table class always takes the width of it's parent but if it does not do that for you then u simply add the col-xs-12 class. `class='project_info_1 table table-striped... col-xs-12'`
Remember we use col-xs-12 because it must have the same width of it's parent no matter what device it is on

Comment: you can also for add `display: block; width: auto;` or `display: block; width: 100%;` to your project_info_1 css properties and see if that would help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">

   <div class="col-md-6">
      //FIRST DIV HERE
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
     //SECOND DIV HERE
   </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

'Class' is misspelled. You have used 'clas' instead of "class"